# ionic on IOS Google Maps JavaScript API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError

Tags: ios, angular, google-maps, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm developing an app on ionic platform, I'm trying to get some information from Google API to show on map.

In ionic 4.7.1 on IOS I try to access Google Maps services and get the following error:

> Google Maps JavaScript API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError
> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#referer-not-allowed-map-error
> Your site URL to be authorized: ionic://my-domain/home/appointments-new/appointments-search-fields

The request with an ionic prefix instead of https prefix and causes a CORS error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RefererNotAllowedMapError` means that the current URL loading the Maps JavaScript API has not been added to the list of allowed referrers, as per Error Messages documentation (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages).

As per the error message you have shared, you can add ionic://my-domain/home/appointments-new/appointments-search-fields to your list of website restrictions for the API key you're using. The steps on how to do this can be found here:

- https://developers.google.com/maps/api-security-best-practices
- https://youtu.be/2_HZObVbe-g